# gem dependency conflict because of nori

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, appdirect

how to resolve this type of errors

```
In Gemfile:
    appdirect (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nori (~> 2.4) ruby

    google-adwords-api (>= 0) ruby depends on
      google-ads-common (~> 0.9.8) ruby depends on
        savon (~> 1.2.0) ruby depends on
          nori (1.1.5)
```

Please tell. I tried updating google-adword-api gem but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited appdirect to use compitable version of nori.
Here is the link to the gem

> https://github.com/aditya01933/appdirect

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `google-ads-common` gem is [sticked](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/issues/15#issuecomment-76444075) to old version of `savon`, here's what gem author says:

> Savon 2 does not support the complex AdWords API wsdls. I would love to upgrade and put this to rest, but it isn't feasible at the moment. We are looking into alternatives.

In this sad situation you need to choose between conflicting gems, you can't have both at once.